# FreeMarker Error : left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this evaluated to a sequence

Tags: freemarker

When I loop through a list in freemarker like below, it works fine.

```
<#list cModel.products as product>
```

But when I'm tring to assign the size of the list to a variable like,

```
 <#assign totalProducts = cModel.products.getList()?size>
```

I'm getting an exception from free marker like below

> left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this evaluated to a sequence

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the signature of `Product.getList()`? Post the Java.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I Hope you've accessing it wrongly.

As per your example, the list name is product. So,

```
<#assign totalProducts = cModel.getProducts()?size>
```

Should return back the size of the products.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `cModel.products?size` is the nicer way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Having json:

```
{
    "domain": {
        "kingdom": []
    },
}
```

We create a variable and assign the size of the kingdom list to it.

```
<#assign kingdomLen = domain.kingdom?size>   
<#if kingdomLen > 0 >
    We have kingdoms!
</#if>
```

And that is how we use it in an if-example.